# MSVS linker error unless the whole solution is rebuilt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, linker

As part of my current project at work, I have to write several unit tests to test the behavior of our main software.

Our solution is structured the following way:

- The main software has its own project, and is compiled as a Win32 .exe
- The unit tests are in a different projects but in the same solution. When I want to run the tests, I have to change recompile the main software to produce a .lib static library file.

For a while everything worked okay, I could switch between compiling the main software as .exe or as .lib and then run the tests without any problem.

However, at some point I started getting linker errors when trying to compile the unit test project. As before, I change the settings of the main software to compile as a .lib, then recompile it. The .lib file is produced at the right location. Then I go and compile the unit test projects, which throws plenty "unresolved external symbol" linker errors to function calls in unit tests that were already implemented, I did not touch, and compiled fine before without any linker errors. But the weird thing is, if I rebuild the whole project, everything works just fine.

My question is, what could cause this linker problem so suddenly?

**Things I tried to solve this issue:**

- Made sure that the two projects use the same Character Set
- Made sure that the unit test project is correctly linked to the main software. Meaning that I added the .lib as an `External Dependency`, added the folder containing it as an `Additional Library Directory`, and added the folder containing the header files as an `Include Directory`.
- Checked that all the functions that throw the error are actually implemented and are used as expected.

Comment: Have you checked the build order for the unit tests project?

Comment: You probably have a linker dependency that your solution hasn't set correctly. e.g. project A depends on B but you've not stated this so they build out of order or at the same time. Right click on each `project->properties` then go to `Linker->Input`. See what you've included in `Additional dependencies`. You then need to set the project build dependencies, right-click on the affected `projects->Build dependencies...` select `Project Build Order` and check the projects it depends on and the solution should then build correctly

Comment: @DingusKhan The unit test project is at the last place in the solution.

Comment: @EdChum In the unit test project the only `Additional Dependencies` are inherited .libs and the .lib of the main software. The `Project Dependencies` are set correctly as far as I can tell, the unit test project should only depend on the main software, and as I said in my other comment, the unit test project is the last in the `Project Build Order`.

Comment: Suggestion - create a new project that always builds the "main software" as a .lib file, and leave alone the project that builds it as an .exe.  This will involve referencing files from the original project.  Make sure the unit test project depends on this new project.  Doing this will slightly increase your build times, but it keeps things a lot cleaner and circumvents some of the "magic" that MSBuild/Tracker do during builds.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker That is definitely something worth considering. I was hoping that there was an easier(?) solution but if not, creating a new project might be a reasonable idea.

Comment: Perhaps we could be of more assistance if you'd paste at least part of the actual unresolved symbol messages